# Right way to store several addresses and select one as main/principal

Tags: sql-server, rdbms, entity-framework

I'm working in a little model and I'm struggling with a simple question.

How should I store a list of addresses/mails/phones and select one as principal?

Example I'm thinking now.

**AddressEntity**:

- Id
- Bla bla fields

**PersonEntity**:

- Id
- Bla bla bla names and bday, etc...
- List of addresses (in a many-to-many to Addresses, because one address can be shared within a family members)
- Principal Address (FK - Addresses)

This is the entity I made in EF Core:

```
public class Person
{
    public Person()
    {
        Addresses = new HashSet<Address>();
        PhoneNumbers = new HashSet<PhoneNumber>();
        Emails = new HashSet<Email>();
    }

    [StringLength(100)]
    public string Firstname { get; set; } = null!;

    [StringLength(300)]
    public string Lastname { get; set; } = null!;

    public Gender Gender { get; set; }

    public DateTime BirthDate { get; set; }

    public Guid? MainAddressId { get; set; }

    public Address MainAddress { get; set; } = null!;

    public virtual ICollection<Address> Addresses { get; internal set; }
}
```

But this looks to dirty to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you:

AddressEntity:

- Id
- Bla bla fields

PersonEntity:

- Id
- Bla bla bla names and bday, etc...

PersonAddressRelation:

- Person Id
- Address Id
- Is_principal address attribute

Comment: Is_Principal is a simple boolean? In that case, thanks, I wouldn't have reach that never.

Comment: @DrkDeveloper, also consider creating a unique filtered index to ensure only one address per person is primary: `CREATE UNIQUE INDEX idx_PersonAddressRelation_PersonID_IsPrinciple ON dbo.PersonAddressRelation(PersonID, IsPrinciple) WHERE IsPrinciple = 1;`. In addition to data integrity, the index may improve performance when only principle addresses are queried.